# Looping through active sheets ignoring particular sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to loop through sheets, and remove row entries that are not equal to sheet name.

I've if statements to ignore particular sheets.

It will only work on one sheet and won't loop through all.

```
Sub CleanRegionalSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngx As Long

    With ws
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ActiveSheet.Name = "Raw Data" Then
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Building Status" Then
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Clean Data" Then
            Else
                For lngx = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
                    If Cells(lngx, "A").Value <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
                        Cells(lngx, "A").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Updated code, still not working:

```
Sub CleanRegionalSheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngx As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Raw Data" Then
    ElseIf ws.Name = "Building Status" Then
    ElseIf ws.Name = "Clean Data" Then
    Else
        For lngx = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
            If Cells(lngx, "A").Value <> ws.Name Then
                Cells(lngx, "A").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `With` and `End With` and replace `ActiveSheet` with `ws`.

Comment: Looping over sheets doesn't make them active. That is, the activesheet will remain the same *unless* you activate each sheet that you want. But you needn't do that. Just change your usage of `ActiveSheet` to the worksheet variable `ws`, and your code should work.

Comment: You're also using an implicit call to ActiveSheet with `Cells`. You'll need to chage that to `ws.Cells`, or use `.Cells` (if you choose to exploit the `With ws` block)

Comment: Updated, but still can't get it; did I miss something?

Comment: @LiamHendricken yes, there's also an implicit ActiveSheet reference in `Rows`, which needs to be `ws.Rows`.

Comment: My, look how much more amazingly readable and maintainable the code that I indented for you is. If you installed Rubberduck for indenting, you'd be amazed all day long - you'd get indenting and implicit ActiveSheet inspections for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ws object. Try this (you also forgot to enable ScreenUpdate at the end):

```
Sub CleanRegionalSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngx As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Raw Data", "Building Status", "Clean Data"
            Case Else
                With ws
                    For lngx = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
                        If .Cells(lngx, "A").Value <> .Name Then
                            .Rows(lngx).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        End If
                    Next
                End With
        End Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: still has an implicit reference to Activesheet `Rows`, so this code is buggy.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I presume the OP wants to be able to run it on what ever the **ActiveWorkbook** is. If OP only wants to do it on the Workbook this macro resides, the `ActiveWorkbook` should be replaced by `ThisWorkbook`. Where do you see Activesheet? Anyway, `Rows.Count` is same independent of which worksheet (application limit).

Comment: @Patrick The For Loop is looping over Worksheets of the ActiveWorkbook *without* activating them. Calling `Rows` will be called against the ActiveSheet of the ActiveWorkbook, not the sheet that you're currently enumerating. In this particular instance, Rows is returning the Count, and as you point out, that will be the same for all Worksheets, but it would be better if the sheet reference was made explicit, or you could end up performing actions on rows on the wrong sheet.